# how to use n value's n power in ruby 1.8.6

Tags: ruby

Is there any method available in ruby 1.8.6 for calculating n values n power?

Like 2 has 5 power then answer is 32 and 5 has 3 power then answer is 125?

Comment: Aside from, e.g., `2**5` or `5**3`?

Comment: Sorry for asking . Thanks for replying. .. :P

Comment: I upvoted this question, but only to bring it back from -1... I think it's a valid question for SO, but I also upvoted Marc B's RTFM comment, and I could do, I upvote it twice because it provides "the authorative link". My opinion is that simple factual questions belong on SO too... because SO is designed to be indexed by google **using the questioners language**, which creates a "synonym cloud" that allows ME to find MY stuff quickly, despite not knowing "the official name" for it.

Comment: Hi @Marc, while I wholeheartedly welcome your manual links on these kinds of questions, would you consider putting them more politely for the sake of their survival? :)  There's at least one user systematically flagging them for rudeness, he even asked a Meta question about it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167763/rudeness-cleanup-2-15-13 (now deleted after heavy downvoting) I fear that the flagging activity makes the comments go away, which is a shame because the links are usually productive.

Comment: @pekka: no problem. RTL(inked)M perhaps?

Comment: @Marc heh! What I like to do is something like "this is explained in the manual" or (if it's a really lazy user) "You should have looked in the manual first:"

Comment: though I really do like rtfm. It's just... "traditional". rather like telling someone to punch themselves in the middle of their face when they ask where their nose is.

Comment: @Marc yeah, I know what you mean. But the "F" in it arguably makes it rude under SO's guidelines, and it *does* come across a bit blunt. Padding them with niceness makes sure they don't get flagged :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2**5 will give you the result 32.